# How to construct a pivot table that contains values based on certain conditions

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, powerpivot

I want to construct a pivot table from a huge data-set. Now I want to construct the pivot table that consists of values based on certain specified conditions, for example, the entries with age>25 will only be populated in the pivot table. How to do that without manually filtering out data from the constructed pivot table?

Comment: What is the source data of the pivot table? SQL Connection? Range?

Comment: It is a sheet within the workbook itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve has no clean solution, I can think of two dirty ones.

1. Modify the source data/clone the source data and modify that
2. Modify the `SourceData` property of the pivot table by code

Option 1 is easier, safer, but not good if you are working with large amounts of data.

Option 2 is trickier, it would require you to change the data the pivot table is using and limiting it to only what you want. To use your example, you would sort the data by Age (descending), programmatically find where does the range of rows with Age >25 end end use only that range as `SourceData` for your pivot table.

Not nice, but these would get the job one. That saying, I wouldn't use either of these. The pivot table filtering is there for a reason.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While I too want to refrain from using either of these. I actually wanted to compare values of  two different columns and create a pivot table for only those entries for whom values don't match. Neither of the above two would actually work for that. Anyways, thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, in that case you can create a calculated field in the pivot table comparing the two columns, returning TRUE or FALSE and just filter the pivot table on that, without needing any cheap tricks.